# Cgi script is printing the html text file rather rendering it in the browser while sourcing the module

Tags: perl, cgi

I have following code

```
#file 1 a.pm
package a;
@Export=(test);

print "test"; #hashing this is enabling the rendering 

sub test {
  return 1;
} 

#file 2 main cgi script test.pl
use a;
my $t = test();
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html>\n<body>\n<p>test= $t</p></body>\n</html>";
```

While hashing the print line in module a is enabling the rendering but when print statement is enable, it is unable to do it?

Comment: Try running the script from the command line and you will see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `use` the `a` module, the `print "test"` is executed. i.e. `test` is printed before the `Content-type` header. Furthermore, your `Content-type` header turns into `testContent-type`.